# How would I express that what someone says is a challenge?

Tags: phrasing

Let's say  that two people are having a conversation and one of them says something like

> Try me, Tom. Then I will surrender."

I'd like to add a "he says" statement. Should the "he says" say "He said, hinting a challenge", "he challenges" or something else?

Thank you in advance!

I'm going to guess "he says, hinting a challenge" is most clear?

Comment: "Try me, Tom. Then, I will surrender", he challenged.

Comment: This might be better for writers.SE.

Comment: Remember the old writer's adage: *show*, don't *tell*.  "Try me, Tom" is already a *challenge*.  Saying "this is a challenge" adds nothing -- if you must, add some physical description that enhances the image.  Otherwise leave it alone.  But yeah, probably not suited for ELU.

Comment: I think that it's useful to use all kinds of verbs instead of he said; He challenged, he retorted, she snipped, she quibbled, she snorted. They are a wealth of verbs from which to choose in English. Try me, Tom without saying challenged could be an entreaty. It is not necessarily a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple tags are usually the least distracting to the reader. I would go with the standard:

> "Try me, Tom," he said, "then I will surrender."

I think the nature of the challenge will come through just fine without explicitly using the word "challenge." At the end of the day, it's still the author's judgement call, but this might alleviate some potential overthinking.